# How can I change a keyboard shortcut in Mint 17.1 Cinnamon?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, linux-mint, cinnamon

I have just installed Mint 17.1 Cinnamon and I'm finding keyboard shortcuts conflicting with Intellij and Emacs. The one giving me a lot of trouble is the Ins key (lower left of the six keys between the alpha keyboard and the keypad).

When I hit Ins, the display flashes. Using gconf-editor and dconf-editor and the keyboard settings panel, I have been unable to find any binding for Ins. How can I change it?

More generally, is there a text file somewhere storing the keyboard shortcuts? I would prefer to edit that directly than deal with these UIs.

Answer (score 3):

Open Keyboard app and go to Keyboard shortcuts tab. In this place you can change bindings.

Answer (score 2):

To find shortcut assigned to `Insert` key try command:

```
gsettings list-recursively | grep Ins
```

According to manual of `dconf-editor`:

```
The gsettings(1) utility provides similar functionality on the commandline.
```